# How to display loading dialog until data is fetched in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, web-deployment

I want to display a loading dialog or screen until my data is completely fetched but don't know how to do it I saw some examples about async/await and promises but from there I am not getting any idea.so, please help me if someone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag variable to decide to show the dialog or not.

```js
let flag = false # disable dialog in default

# bind the update function to some element
async update(){
  flag = true # enable dialog before api call
  const data = await fetchData() # fetch data
  flag = false # disable dialog after all data is fetched
}
```